# Why does savon client.call use a GET request with a payload instead of a POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

```
client.call(:schedule_email_message, xml: '<soapelem />') # actually a GET request, with payload. Why not a POST request?
```

savon gem version: 2.11.1

Comment: @tjarrat do you know?

Answer (score 2):

How do you know it's a GET?

If you look into `lib/savon/operation.rb` line 94 (my version 2.3.0) then you'll see that there is a reference to `HTTPI.post`. Savon uses the HTTPI gem as interface to whatever httpclient gem is installed on your machine.
I'm not sure that has changed since 2.11.1.

https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/version2/lib/savon/operation.rb

Comment: Thanks, yeah I noticed that myself. I'm not entirely sure, I will debug some more. Does Savon on a call first perform a GET to get the WSDL and then a POST if the method specified (`:schedule_email_message` here), is a POST operation?

Comment: I **guess** it GETs the WSDL first. I prefer not to use a WSDL because I think it's too chatty.